# Is there a bijection from 3-dimensional to 2-dimensional cartesian space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry

Given a set $ M $ of coordinates in 3-dimensional cartesian space. Is it possible to find a bijection to 2-dimensional cartesian space?

(This question arose from a rather practical problem of visualizing a 3D "form", consisting of a set of coordinates on a 2-dimensional plane, without losing information)

Comment: Continuous? No. Just a bijection of sets? Yes (as is true for $A^2$ and $A^3$ where $A$ is *any* infinite set).

Comment: @MikeMiller: Thanks for the answer. Yes just a bijection of sets, since it is more a problem of visualization. Can you maybe give me a hint, where to find more information about this or give a simple example in case of a finite set? That would be very helpful :)

Comment: It's of course not true in the case of finite sets. If A has n elements, then $A^2$ has $n^2$ elements and $A^3$ has $n^3$ elements, which are rarely equal. But look up "Square of set in bijection with original set" or something similar.

Comment: Just to be clear, any bijection of sets that you get between 3-d and 2-d cartesian space will by utterly unvisualizable. Such bijections fail to be continuous, and so whatever 3-d form you are trying to visualize will be torn into shreds and then re-assembed as a completely unrecognizable 2-d mess.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are bijections, simply because of cardinality. But they're not at all *smooth*, and of little help with visualization. Certainly there are no linear bijections. (If you assume there is one, using the $rank$ function you can quickly prove that $0 = 1$.) [Space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) are continuous surjections from the unit interval or the reals $\Bbb R$ to higher-dimensional cubes or all of $\Bbb R^n$spaces. They aren't and can't be bijections.

A projection of a set $A$ to another set $B$ in a lower-dimensional space is inherently "lossy". Say you have a 3-dimensional set $A\subseteq \Bbb R^3$. Projecting it onto its first two coordinates gives a set $B = \{(x,y)\mid \exists z\, (x,y,z)\in A\}$. Equivalently, we can think of it as a subset of the 2-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ "the z=0 plane". 
Going from $A$ to $B$ discards information, in general, if $A$ is intrinsically higher-dimensional. If you formerly knew that $(1,2,3)\in A$, now you only know that $(1,2,z)\in A$ for some $z$. You've replaced a constant with an existential quantifier over all reals, and gone from a lookup to a search over an uncountable set. Surely that's a loss of information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brian, that made it clear to me :).

Comment: You're welcome, thank you.